# Emacs - Better completion mechanism for comint mode?

Tags: emacs

When I open a shell in Emacs and try to <kbd>Tab</kbd>-complete paths, this stupid window pops up:

```
Click <mouse-2> on a completion to select it.
In this buffer, type RET to select the completion near point.

Possible completions are:
../     ./  .DS_Store   .git/     bar/     foo/
```

Is there a way I could use a minibuffer completion instead of this awful window, such as Ido or Icicles, or maybe even auto-complete.el?

Comment: Thats really very good question, I also dislike window popping to just show the possible completion.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't solve what you wanted, but you should use `ansi-term`, it's a much better shell emulator than the normal `shell` command. It has two *modes* where one acts like a regular emacs buffer (`C-p` goes up and `C-n` goes down) and the other mode acts like a normal shell (`C-p` for previous command and `C-n` for next command). And in both modes tab just completes like a normal shell.

Comment: How do you switch between said modes?

Comment: `C-c C-k` and `C-c C-j`.